# Circular dependency in two classes - code doesn't compile

Tags: c++, g++, dependencies, header-files, circular-dependency

So, I'm trying to develop a really simple game in C++ (I always used C#, I'm just diving into C++), and wanted to replicate my simple (though poorly designed) component-entity system I made with C#.

This code doesn't compile using g++ with C++11 standard.

How can I fix it? Do I have to change the design, or is there a workaround?

---

Well formatted pastie: http://pastie.org/5078993

---

**Eclipse error log**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void push_back(Component * const &)
'   Entity.cpp  /TestEntity line 15 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Component * *,std::vector<Component *,std::allocator<Component *>>> erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Component * *,std::vector<Component *,std::allocator<Component *>>>)
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Component * *,std::vector<Component *,std::allocator<Component *>>> erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Component * *,std::vector<Component *,std::allocator<Component *>>>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Component * *,std::vector<Component *,std::allocator<Component *>>>)
'   Entity.cpp  /TestEntity line 19 Semantic Error
Method 'update' could not be resolved   Entity.cpp  /TestEntity line 22 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
#0 remove(#0, #0, const #1 &)
'   Entity.cpp  /TestEntity line 19 Semantic Error
```

---

**Component.h**

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_H_
#define COMPONENT_H_

class Entity;

class Component {
private:
    Entity* parentPtr;

public:
    virtual void init();
    virtual void update();
    virtual ~Component();
    void setParent(Entity* mParentPtr);
};

#endif /* COMPONENT_H_ */
```

---

**Component.cpp**

```
#include "Component.h"

void Component::setParent(Entity* mParentPtr) { parentPtr = mParentPtr; }
```

---

**Entity.h**

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H_
#define ENTITY_H_

#include "Component.h"

class Entity {
private:
    std::vector<Component*> componentPtrs;

public:
    ~Entity();
    void addComponent(Component* mComponentPtr);
    void delComponent(Component* mComponentPtr);
    void update();
};

#endif /* ENTITY_H_ */
```

---

**Entity.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Entity.h"
#include "Component.h"

Entity::~Entity() {
    for (auto &componentPtr : componentPtrs) delete componentPtr;
}
void Entity::addComponent(Component* mComponentPtr) {
    componentPtrs.push_back(mComponentPtr);
    mComponentPtr->setParent(this);
}
void Entity::delComponent(Component* mComponentPtr) {
    componentPtrs.erase(remove(componentPtrs.begin(), componentPtrs.end(), mComponentPtr), componentPtrs.end());
    delete mComponentPtr;
}
void Entity::update() { for (auto &componentPtr : componentPtrs) componentPtr->update(); }
```

Comment: Have you tried a forward declaration of the `Component` class in `Entity.h` instead of including the header file, just like you do with `Entity` in `Component.h`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just tried. Same problem

Comment: It's unclear from the error messages which file is even being compiled, but I just tried compiling both Component.cpp and Entity.cpp with both g++ 4.3.3 and MSVC++ 9 (after commenting out the definitions of `Entity::~Entity()` and `Entity::update()` which use the `auto` C++11-ism) and they both compile it happily without errors. So I'm certain the error is not coming from these files.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Very strange. I tried doing what you did and compiling again (still using C++11 and latest MinGW) and I don't get the "update" error anymore but the compiler complains about "invalid arguments" to the push_back method: "Description Resource Path Location Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void push_back(Component * const &)
' Entity.cpp /TestEntity line 15 Semantic Error
"

Comment: I've never seen a compiler give error messages starting with "Description Resource Path Location...".  Could you try running `g++ -c Entity.cpp` from the command line directly, and tell us what error messages you get?

Comment: @j_random_hacker It worked with -c, but it generates a .o file I can't use. If I don't use -c, the same error as the one in Eclipse appear. I think it's because I include Entity.h in Entity.cpp, and Entity.h already included Component.h so Entity.cpp will not include it again. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: If it works with -c then it compiles. The error must therefore be occurring at link time, but the only link-time errors I've previously seen have been caused by missing or duplicate symbols -- something like invalid argument types would be picked up at compilation. Separately: all .cpp files are compiled *completely* in isolation from each other, so e.g. the preprocessor symbols #defined by one don't affect any others.  Separate .cpp files can't influence each other until link time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker What kind of link error could be causing the the compiler to not find the "update" method of a Component object? I've stripped down the useless code and the error still remains, maybe this is easier to analyze: http://pastie.org/5079686

Comment: First of all, if you compile *without* -c, then you need to provide all the .cpp files on the command line (i.e. `g++ Entity.cpp Component.cpp`).  Are you?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I did that now and it compiled successfully, with an .exe I can open! Why does Eclipse keep complaining?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. I've never used Eclipse.

Comment: @j_random_hacker This is what Eclipse calls: g++ -O0 -o "src\\Entity.o" "..\\src\\Entity.cpp" - this has to be the problem, right?

Comment: Either it should use -c when compiling each .cpp file and then link them together in a separate step, or it should omit -c and specify all the .cpp files on a single command line.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It creates a working .exe file now, but still lists the error in the output window. I suppose it's just Eclipse's fault now. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope you can persuade Eclipse to be reasonable :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker I figured it out! The "errors" Eclipse is reporting are actually Code Analysis problems. It's amazing how the developers thought it was a good idea to place them in the same category as compiler errors by default. Fortunately, I was able to customize them to only appear as a warning. :) Also, could you post a simple answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there are actually no circular dependency problems, and the code compiles and links fine.  The "error" is actually just overzealous Code Analysis reporting by Eclipse -- compiling each .cpp file separately on the command line with

```
g++ -c thatfile.cpp
```

produces no compilation errors, and compiling and linking in one go with

```
g++ Entity.cpp Component.cpp
```

produces a working executable.

Comment: Thanks again! I also filed a bug/suggestion report on the Eclipse CDT BugZilla page.

Answer (score 0):

You must include `Entity.h` into `component.cpp`

Comment: I tried doing that, but the same error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that the problem are not circular includes, but the code itself? For example: "Method 'update' could not be resolved" gives you a hint, that you have to define the `Component::update` method, same with the `Component::init`-method, since they are not pure virtual. Try removing this errors first, and then look if this helps

**Update:**
So... i tested your code. Not with eclipse but with Visual Studio 2008. I replaced  the `for (auto...` stuff with "normal" `for (std::vector<Component*>::iterator...`, since this was not available in this version of VS. As i can say, there is no circular dependency but you forgot the `#include <vector>` in your Entity.h file. And the definitions of those virutal functions were missing, but you said, that you added them already, so forget about that ;)

Comment: I can make this error go away by commenting those methods out. But the "invalid parameter" error still remains